# Silverlight can't hitting wcf duplex after third request

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, silverlight, duplex

I have problem with a duplex service after third request silverlight can't hit the server.

This problem appears if I host the service, not locally.

This is the web.config of the service :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="pollingDuplex" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexHttpBindingCollectionElement,System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorAction" name="SilverlightServiceLib.ServiceImplementations.SystemServerAssistantLibrary">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="SilverlightServiceLib.ServiceContracts.ISystemServerAssistantLibrary">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightBehaviorAction" name="SilverlightServiceLib.ServiceImplementations.SystemServiceLibrary">
        <endpoint binding="pollingDuplex" bindingConfiguration="PollingDuplexBinding" contract="SilverlightServiceLib.ServiceContracts.ISystemServiceLibrary">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviorAction">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="SilverlightBehaviorAction">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="9999999"
                maxConcurrentInstances="9999999" maxConcurrentSessions="9999999" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <pollingDuplex>
        <binding name="PollingDuplexBinding"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                 inactivityTimeout="04:00:00" serverPollTimeout="00:02:00" >
          <readerQuotas
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </pollingDuplex>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding"
                   closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                   sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: there is no error , but after third hit this service stuck and take more than 10 min to response